# How to unmarshal multi dimensional array inside struct

Tags: arrays, go, struct

I have following data:-

```
{"me":[{"id": "0xcfd","Title":"Story of Stackoverflow","Users":[{"id":"1","Name":"MetaBoss"},{"id":"2","Name":"Owner"}],"Tag":"golang,programming"}]}
```

and I have the following struct:-

```
type Root struct {
    ID string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Title string `json:"Title,omitempty"`
    Myuser Users `json:"Users,omitempty"` // Users is struct
    Tag string `json:"Tag,omitempty"`
}

type Users struct {
    ID string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name string `json:"Name,omitempty"`
}
```

To unmarshal the data, I am trying to do following things -

```
type Unmarh struct {
    Me []Root `json:"me"`
}

var r Unmarh
err = json.Unmarshal(response, &r)
```

while printing `r.Me[0].Myuser`, I am not able to get data.

I am getting below error -

`json: cannot unmarshal array into go struct field Root.Myuser of type User struct {....Users struct data}`

It needs `Myuser` to be multidimensional `array` type and not `Users` struct. I have no Idea, how to represent `Users` `multidimensional array` inside `struct`

Comment: Users ist nested. Use https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ to generate a suitable Go struct.

Comment: So, is the `Root` struct too, `Users` is of `Users struct`

Comment: @Volker, but it needs to `Users` to be `array` and not `Users` struct. I have no Idea, how to provide `multi dimensional array` inside `struct`

Comment: Do `Myuser []Users`, and maybe choose better names.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/azE7kPFs02V

Comment: @mkopriva - better names?

Comment: Well in the json the key is Users but you call it Myuser and then you have a type Users that respresents a single user... that is confusing.

Comment: @user3767643 see the example in my second comment, it works and makes objectively more sense.

Comment: @mkopriva can you post that as answer, I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the json the `Users` key is an array and so the corresponding Go field should be a slice.

```
type Root struct {
    ID    string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Title string `json:"Title,omitempty"`
    Users []User `json:"Users,omitempty"`
    Tag   string `json:"Tag,omitempty"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/azE7kPFs02V